# Validating against multiple xml schemas with Xerces DOM parser

Tags: c++, xerces, validating

I was wondering if there was a way to validate against multiple xml schemes using Xerces DOM parser in c++?

Here is the use-case: I want to be able to parse multiple xml files against its corresponding xsd schema. However, when I initially look at each xml file, I do not know what file it is until I parse it, hence I cannot link a static xsd file to it. Is there a way of saying, I want to validate each xml file against xsd1 or xsd2 or etc...

After reading around it appears the settings of the parser 'setExternalSchemaLocation' is able to hold a list of schemes but when I do this in my code, it doesn't validate correctly.

```
parser->setExternalSchemaLocation("http://www.somelocation schema.xsd http://www.somelocation schema1.xsd");
```

The schema works by itself if I did

```
parser->setExternalSchemaLocation("http://www.somelocation schema.xsd");
```

So I am certain there is no error in my xml or xsd file.

Any insights into how to validate against multiple xml schemas?

Comment: have you tried setting the schemas separately as two commands instead of the one line? something like :parser->setExternalSchemaLocation("http://www.somelocation schema.xsd"); parser->setExternalSchemaLocation("http://www.somelocation schema1.xsd");

Comment: @Sii: that's not going to work, the Xerces doc says: "If this method is called more than once, only the last one takes effect."

Comment: @Sii Yes I've tried the two commands seperately and as Eugen mentioned, it overwrites each other.

Comment: @Eugen Sorry, there is no error message. That was a typo on my part. I want Xerces to be able to throw an error when the xml does not match the schema. This action is successfully performed when I compare it against one schema. When I attempt to compare it against multiple schema (like the code snippet above) it doesn't fail when it should. So I was wondering if there was a way to validate an xml file against multiple schemas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code does not work if each xml is in the same namespace. Each xml file must be in a different namespace in order for the code above to work.

```
parser->setExternalSchemaLocation("http://www.somelocation schema.xsd http://www.somelocation1 schema1.xsd");
```